# React - how to make my page render again?

Tags: reactjs, render

What I want is for my page to re-render after useEffect is executed
I have a page that before it is rendered I need to dispatch an action to change the state of a variable, this action is dispatched inside useEffect, and after that I want my page refreshed I want it to be re-rendered

```
export default function Dashboard() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(googleCheckLogIn());
  }, []);

  function handleClickSum() {
    history.push('/pesquisarAulas');
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Content>
        <MainOverview>
          <OverviewCard onClick={handleClickSum}>
            <div className="overviewcard__icon">
              <FaPen size="30" id="penIcon" />
            </div>
            <div className="overviewcard__info">
              <span>Lançar Sumário</span>
            </div>
          </OverviewCard>
          <OverviewCard>
            <div className="overviewcard__icon">
              <AiFillCalculator size="30" id="calculatorIcon" />
            </div>
            <div className="overviewcard__info">
              <span>Lançar Nota</span>
            </div>
          </OverviewCard>
          <OverviewCard>
            <div className="overviewcard__icon">
              <FaBook size="30" id="bookIcon" />
            </div>
            <div className="overviewcard__info">
              <span>Unidades Curriculares</span>
            </div>
          </OverviewCard>
          <OverviewCard>
            <div className="overviewcard__icon">
              <BsCardChecklist size="30" id="cardCheckIcon" />
            </div>
            <div className="overviewcard__info">
              <span>Marcar Presença</span>
            </div>
          </OverviewCard>
        </MainOverview>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can implement [forceUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-forceupdate) to force a component to rerender even when no props or state have changed. It's not good practice though. From what you've shown, there's not a good reason for this component to rerender. Only components that use your updated variable should need to rerender, and that will happen automatically if they recieve it as a prop.

Comment: create a state variable using `useState` and update this variable inside useEffect, or pass in the `state` and `updateState` methods as arguments if you need to update the parent(or use redux)